# Find regular expression string and replace it in R

Tags: r, regex

The purpose is to tidy a dataset by cleaning all variable names replications.
A typical example:

```
var.name <- "blue cat"  #"true" variable name
```

is found in the dataset with the following entries/replications:

```
char <- c("blue cat","blue cat blueing","blue cats",
          "blue cat dog", "blue catts cat","blue cat cat")
```

The ideal result is to get all of the above replications renamed as **var.name**, ie "blue cat". The following grep(..) does that:

```
char[grep(paste("blue cat", collapse="|"), char, value=F)] <- var.name
```

The drawback of this method is that one has to manually search & enter all **char** occurrences. The ideal solution will be to parse **"blue cat"** by a regular expression and replace it where the string is matched.

Any ideas? Thanks so much.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want.  Do you want all instances of char containing `blue cat` to be renamed simply `blue cat`, or do you want all instances of char containing `flash flood` to be renamed `blue cat`?

Comment: Hi Benjamin, I have corrected the confusing typo (copy-paste). All instances need to be found and replaced by `blue cat`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to parse by a regular expression, this would suffice.

```
sub('.*blue cat.*', var.name, char)
# [1] "blue cat" "blue cat" "blue cat" "blue cat" "blue cat" "blue cat"
```

Comment: Thanks hwnd! Is there a way to substitute the literal `blue cat` argument 1 in sub() for by var.name directly? Something like: `sub('.*var.name.*',var.name,char)`.

Comment: `sub(paste0('.*', var.name, '.*'), var.name, char)`  Is what I think you want.

Comment: Much appreciated. One of the best places on the net!

Answer (score 2):

No as slick as hwnd's but still functional

```
char[grepl("blue cat", char)] <- var.name
```

`grepl` returns a logical instead of a numeric.  If you wanted to get code that is a little more transparent, you could use `str_detect` from the `stringr` package

```
char[str_detect(char, "blue cat")] <- var.name
```

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. `stringer` 's `str_detect` looks really interesting. Do you anticipate in difference(s) from `sub()` as proposed by hwnd?

Comment: I anticipate do difference at all between the two of them.  I actually rather like hwnd's.  My only comment is that if I were to use hwnd's, I might not remember what it means six months from now.  But that's a style issue, not a substance issue.

Comment: Applying the solution, I came across another issue: misspellings in **var.name**. A typical example is _blue caat_. Would it be possible to save this entry in the parsing?